# React Js dynamic modal page for every product with scroolY localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I want to get dynamic content for my products inside modal view instead of having pages for them but i am working with someonelses code so i don't want to mess with it
Here is the code for image link creator for products pages

```
        <div className="col-xs-12 no-padding home-product-container component-product-list js-component-type-weekly">
            <Row className="">
                {/* {props.products&&props.products.map((p,index)=>
                    <Col md={3} sm={6} xs={6} className="mb-3 productOverviewCol">
                        <Card className="pt-3 pb-3" className="prodOverviewCard" id={p.ProdNo}> */}
                {props.products && props.products.map((p, index) =>
                    // {props.products&&props.products.slice(((props.page - 1)*(props.itemsPerPage)),(props.page)*(props.itemsPerPage)).map((p,index)=>
                    <Col md={3} sm={6} xs={6} className="productOverviewCol">
                        <Card className="pt-3 pb-3 prodOverviewCard" id={p.ProdNo}>
                            <div className="bkggrey">
                                <div className="prodImgWp">
                                    <Link to={{
                                        pathname: `/ProductDetail`,
                                        search: `?id=${p.ProdNo}`,
                                        state: { productType: type, Products: props.products, pageToLoad: props.pageToLoad, customerNo: props.custNo, totalProducts: props.totalProducts }
                                    }} onClick={() => {
                                        setScrollYStore(window.scrollY);
                                        window.localStorage.setItem('scrollY', window.scrollY);
                                    }}>
                                        {/* <CardImg top src={p.Small_Img === "" || p.Small_Img === undefined ? bkry : p.Small_Img} alt="Image" />  */}
                                        <CardImg top src={p.Small_Img === "" || p.Small_Img === undefined ? bkry : p.Small_Img} alt="Image" />
                                    </Link>
                                </div>
                                {p.Price_type_name !== undefined && p.Price_type_name !== "Kundpris" ? <span className="BestDealSpan">{p.Price_type_name}</span> : null}
                                {/* <span className="circulrIcn"><AccountCircleIcon className="AccountCirculrIcnprdList" /></span> */}
                            </div>
                            <CardBody className="ProductOverviewCardBody">
                                <CardTitle className="titleTxt my-3">{p.Descr}</CardTitle>

                                <CardText className="CommercialText text-center pb-1">{p.BrandName + ' ' + p.Size_Contains}</CardText>
                                {acessToken ? <><CardSubtitle className="mb-2 greenText">{p.newPrice !== null && p.newPrice !== undefined ? p.newPrice.toFixed(2) : null} kr</CardSubtitle>
                                    <CardText className="Compartiveprice">Jmf.pris : {p.Comp_Price !== null && p.Comp_Price !== undefined ?  p.purchased_Unit === "Kart" ? p.box_com_cart_price.toFixed(2) : p.Comp_Price.toFixed(2) : null}/{p.comp_unit}</CardText></> : null}
                                {p.Campaign === 1 ? <CardText className="priceValidText mb-1">Pris gäller t.o.m {p.CampaignEndDate}</CardText> : null}
                                {acessToken ?
                                    <>
                                        <Row>
                                            <Col>
                                                <CardText className="text-center LadaSelectWp" >

                                                    {(p.Conv_facor_CART === null || p.Conv_facor_CART === 0) && (p.Conv_facor_ST === null || p.Conv_facor_ST === 0) && (p.Conv_facor_KG === null || p.Conv_facor_KG === 0) ? null :
                                                        <select className="minimal" name="select" id="exampleSelect" value={p.default_value}
                                                            onChange={(e) => props.onChangeUnit(e, index, p.ProdNo, p.Standard_orderunit, p.Comp_Price, p.Price_broken, p.Price_cart, p.Conv_facor_KG, p.Conv_facor_ST, p.Conv_facor_CART, p.default_price)}
                                                            disabled={p.Conv_facor_CART === 0 && p.Conv_facor_KG === 0 ? true : p.Conv_facor_ST === 0 && p.Conv_facor_KG === 0 ? true : p.Conv_facor_ST === 0 && p.Conv_facor_CART === 0 ? true : false}>
                                                            {p.Conv_facor_KG === 0 ? null :
                                                                <option value={p.Conv_facor_KG} keyid="Kg">{p.comp_unit === 'Liter' ? `Liter` : `KILO`}</option>}
                                                            {p.Conv_facor_ST === 0 ? null :
                                                                <option value={p.Conv_facor_ST} keyid="Styck">{`${p.Conv_facor_ST} ST`}</option>}
                                                            {p.Conv_facor_CART === 0 ? null :
                                                                <option value={5} keyid="Kart"> Kolli ({(p.Standard_orderunit === "Kart") && p.Conv_facor_ST === 0 ? p.Conv_facor_CART + ' ' + "ST" : (p.Standard_orderunit === "Kart") && p.Conv_facor_ST !== 0 ? p.Conv_facor_CART / p.Conv_facor_ST + ' ' + "ST" : p.Standard_orderunit === "Styck" ? p.Conv_facor_CART + ' ' + "ST" : (p.Standard_orderunit === "Kg") ? p.Conv_facor_CART + ' ' + "KG" : null}) </option>}
                                                        </select>}
                                                </CardText>

                                            </Col>
                                        </Row>
                                        <Row>
                                            <Col md={12} className="IncrementListItemWpr">
                                                <CardText className="text-center" >
                                                    <ListGroup horizontal className="my-2 text-center" style={{ margin: '0 auto' }}>
                                                        <ListGroup.Item disabled={p.Min_Quantity === p.newQuantity ? true : false} onClick={() => props.DecreaseItem(p.newQuantity, index, p.ProdNo, p.newPrice, p.Min_Quantity)}>-</ListGroup.Item>
                                                        {p.purchased_Unit === "Kg" && p.comp_unit !== 'Liter' ?
                                                            <Input
                                                                type={"text"}
                                                                className="InputincrementClass"
                                                                // id="depositedAmount"
                                                                pattern="[+-]?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?"
                                                                id={index}
                                                                data-min="1"
                                                                onChange={(e) => props.onChangeQty(e, index, p.newPrice, p.Min_Quantity, p.ProdNo, p.purchased_Unit,p.Max_Quantity)}
                                                                value={p.hiddenText ? p.newQuantity + " KG" : p.newQuantity}
                                                                onClick={() => props.onclcikEvent(p.ProdNo)}
                                                                onBlur={(e) =>
                                                                props.onMouseLeaveEvent(p.ProdNo)}
                                                            /> :
                                                            p.purchased_Unit === "Kg" && p.comp_unit === 'Liter' ?
                                                                <Input
                                                                    type={"text"}
                                                                    className="InputincrementClass"
                                                                    // id="depositedAmount"
                                                                    pattern="[+-]?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?"
                                                                    id={index}
                                                                    data-min="1"
                                                                    onChange={(e) => props.onChangeQty(e, index, p.newPrice, p.Min_Quantity, p.ProdNo, p.purchased_Unit,p.Max_Quantity)}
                                                                    value={p.hiddenText ? `${p.newQuantity} L` : p.newQuantity}
                                                                    onClick={(e) => props.onclcikEvent(p.ProdNo)}
                                                                    onBlur={(e) =>
                                                                    props.onMouseLeaveEvent(p.ProdNo)}
                                                                /> :
                                                                <Input
                                                                    type="text" data-min="1"
                                                                    autoComplete="off"
                                                                    className="InputincrementClass"
                                                                    size="1" name={p.newQuantity}
                                                                    data-max="999"
                                                                    id={index}
                                                                    onChange={(e) => props.onChangeQty(e, index, p.newPrice, p.Min_Quantity, p.ProdNo, p.purchased_Unit,p.Max_Quantity)}
                                                                    value={p.hiddenText ? p.newQuantity + " ST" : p.newQuantity}
                                                                    onClick={() => props.onclcikEvent(p.ProdNo)}
                                                                    onBlur={(e) =>
                                                                    props.onMouseLeaveEvent(p.ProdNo)}
                                                                />}
                                                        <ListGroup.Item onClick={(e) => props.IncrementItem(p.newQuantity, index, p.ProdNo, p.newPrice, p.Min_Quantity,p.Max_Quantity)} >+</ListGroup.Item>
                                                    </ListGroup>
                                                </CardText>
                                            </Col>
                                        </Row>
                                    </>
                                    : null}

                                {/* {acessToken?
                                    <Button className="w-100 btnAddShop mt-1" onClick={()=>{saveToCart(p)}}>Add to Cart</Button> :
                                    <Button className="w-100 btnAddShop mt-1" onClick={() => handleShowLogin()}>LOGIN TO SHOP</Button>
                                  }           
                               */}
                            </CardBody>
                            <Row>
                                <Col md={12} className="absoluteBtnCol">
                                    {acessToken ?
                                        <Button className="w-100 btnAddShop mt-1" onClick={() => { saveToCart(p) }}>
                                            {/* Add to Cart */}
                                            LÄGG I VARUKORGEN
                                        </Button> :
                                        <Button className="w-100 btnAddShop mt-1" onClick={() => handleShowLogin()}>
                                            {/* LOGIN TO SHOP */}
                                            LÄGG TILL I KUNDVAGN
                                        </Button>
                                    }
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </Card>

                    </Col>
                )}
            </Row>
            {
                
            props.loading?<label></label>:
                props.productCount === 0 ?
                    <Row className="justify-content-end">
                        <Col xs={12} className="my-3 text-center">
                            {/* "No result for display" */}
                            Inget resultat för visning
                        </Col>
                    </Row> :
                    props.productCount === props.totalProducts ?
                        null :
                        <Row className="justify-content-end">
                            <Col xs={12} className="my-3 text-center">
                                <button onClick={props.loadMore} className="btn loadingbtn">
                                {`LADDA ${(Number(props.totalProducts)-Number(props.productCount))>=24?24:(Number(props.totalProducts)-Number(props.productCount))} AV ${Number(props.totalProducts)-Number(props.productCount)} PRODUKTER`}                                    
                                </button>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
            }
        </div>
```

I have tried to use link to code into modal body with pathname search and state . now product list overview page is like this [Product List Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Gpob.png)